# Getting error:unable to execute js call:_fbBatchedBridge is undefined while executing in simulator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am studying react-native for the first time. I started implementing the tutorial defined in the documentation, But I am getting an error, i also searched for it but nothing worked for me.

Here is my index.ios.js file:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';
//import React,
var {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} = React;

var mocked_movies_data = [{title: 'Title', year:'2016', posters: {thumbnail: 'http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg'}},];

class DemoApp extends Component {
 render()
 {
  var movie = mocked_movies_data[0];
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
    <Text style = {movie.title}></Text>
    <Text style = {movie.year}></Text>
    <Image source = {{uri:movie.posters.thumbnail}}
          style = {styles.thumbnail} />
    </View> 
    );
 } 
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  thumbnail: {
    width: 53,
    height: 81
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('DemoApp', () => DemoApp);
```

And I am getting this error:

> unable to execute js call:_fbBatchedBridge is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution:

At the top of the code I just need to add this line:

> var React = require('react-native');

Comment: I got the same error, can I see your `package.json`?

Comment: which version are you using currently?